# NodeJS - Output multiple values from array into var as string

Tags: node.js

Apologies if this has been asked before, or if there is an existing question regarding this, I'm very new to NodeJS and one of the ways I'm trying to learn is by creating a simple replacement for AlertManager for our site alerting.

The script is very simple, it performs a get to the prometheus api which returns an array of sites that meet the "down" condition. I am iterating through the array and using nodemailer to send an alert for each site that goes down.

I don't think this is very efficient, if there are 3 sites down, 3 emails get sent. It can get quite spammy, I'd like to grab these distinct values and instead of sending an email while I iterate append the value to a variable as a string and then just send that variable as a list.

I can't quite wrap my head around how to do it- this is my current code:

```
while ( arrIndex < failureCount) {
          var currentInstance = failureInstances[arrIndex].metric.instance;

          // Send email
          const message = {
              from: 'alerts@notmyrealemail.com', // Sender address
              to: 'ee@notmyrealemail.com',         // List of recipients
              subject: failureCount + ' Down Sites', // Subject line
              text: 'The following site is down for over 5 minutes: ' + currentInstance + '\n\nHere is additional data:\n' + chunks // Plain text body
          };

          transport.sendMail(message, function(err, info) {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err)
              } else {
                console.log(info);
              }
          });

          arrIndex++
        }

      });
```

I tried changing the while to be inside the variable but that didn't work for what I needed. I looked at other questions and they seem to be centered around doing the opposite (pushing string into array).

Thank you!

### Edit

Adding what the JSON looks like:

{
  "status":"success",
  "data":{
    "resultType":"vector",
    "result":[
      {
        "metric":{
          "**name**":"probe_http_status_code",
          "instance":"https://eetest.com",
          "job":"blackbox",
          "region":"local"
        },
    "value":[
      1583304106.292,
      "0"
      ]
    },
  {
    "metric":{
      "**name**":"probe_http_status_code",
      "instance":"https://anothersitedown.com/",
      "job":"blackbox",
      "region":"local"},
      "value":[
        1583304106.292,
        "0"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}`

This is my code after reworking it using "map"

Added this function:

```
function createFailureMessage(failure) {
var downSite = failure.metric.instance + '\n';
return downSite;
```

}

And removed the while:

```
res.on("end", function() {
    var status = JSON.parse(chunks);
    var failureCount = status.data.result.length;
    var failureInstances = status.data.result;
    var arrIndex = 0;

    //const failureLines = failureInstances.map(failure => createFailureMessage(failure));
    const message = {
        from: 'alerts@notrealemail.com', // Sender address
        to: 'anerdatwork@notrealemail.com',         // List of recipients
        subject: failureCount + ' Down Sites', // Subject line
        text: 'The following are down:\n' + failureInstances.map(failure => createFailureMessage(failure)) // Plain text body
    };

    //send mail
    transport.sendMail(message, function(err, info) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          console.log(info);
        }
    });

  });
```

Comment: So, essentially what you're building is a notification service which i believe should send an email for each site down but i see what you're trying to do here collate all the site downs and send as a single mail.

Now i have a question before i can suggest something 
Is it an async event of fetch of these statuses from websites?

Also, can you post the result array from promethus ?

Comment: @VaibhavKumarGoyal Sorry brother just saw this, it is async, I have the script wrapped in an interval function that essentially reruns itself every 5 minutes. 

I'll post what the Json looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most idiomatic way to do this is with a `map` or `reduce`.  No dealing with indices.

```
const failureLines = failureInstances.map(failure => createFailureMessage(failure));
const emailText = createEmailText(failureLines);
transport.sendEmail(emailText, ...);
```

Comment: I'm coming from PHP, so I think a bit procedurally-  and I'm ignorant to the concept of map, but from the context here and what I found on MDN we are passing a function to map. 

In this context what is 'failure' and what is 'createFailureMessage'

Comment: I worked it and based on your answer I created something that is acceptable for my application. Adding code into edit. Thanks for your help!